# Python 3.3 Install - Freeze - Linux 3.4 Amazon ec2

Tags: installation, centos, python-3.3

I am very new to server setup and have spun up an Amazon stock ec2 server with Linux 3.4 on it.

I am trying to get python 3.3 onto it.  I have so far installed the following:

```
yum install gcc gcc-c++ autoconf automake
```

When I try and run:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/python3.3
```

the output I get freezes on "checking whether gcc accepts -pthread... "

Can you please let me know where to start looking to solve this problem?  I'm using a combination of a few tutorials, but primarily https://askubuntu.com/questions/244544/how-to-install-python-3-3 ?  Unfortunately, this tutorial is for Ubuntu and my server is CentOs.  I therefore, use yum instead of apt-get.

Thank you for your help or guidance.

Comment: I had same problem with Python 2.7, and didn't found solution. Some say problem accrues only on t1.micro server instances.
In case of Python 2.7, workaround is to install python with yum: `sudo yum install python27`

Comment: is there ever an answer to this question? There's no yum package it seems for python3 available on an Ec2 instance?